# jQuery increment by X on each click

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating a next/prev navigation from scratch and would like the click of the "next" button to increase (animate) margin left by X on each click until the end is reached (in this case -320px), similar method for the back button. I am probably being uber dense - but my javascript is below:

```
 function myFunction() {

    "use strict";

    if (jQuery) {
        var $next = $(".next"),
            $back = $(".back"),
            $box = $(".box"),
            regWidth = $box.width(),
            $contain = $(".contain"),
            len = 0,
            combinedWidth = 0,
            len = $box.length;

        while (len--) {

            combinedWidth = combinedWidth + $($box[len]).width();

        }


        $contain.width(combinedWidth);


        $next.bind('click', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();


            var $this = $(this),
                $tWidth = $this.width();



            $contain.animate({

                marginLeft: "+=" + (-regWidth) + "px"

            });

        });

        //click event for back  
        $back.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var $this = $(this),
                $tWidth = $this.width();
            $contain.animate({

                marginLeft: "+=" + (regWidth) + "px"

            });


        });





    }
};

$(function () {

    myFunction();
});
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
#wrap {
    width:320px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;

}
.contain {

    float:left;
    background:#e9e9e9;
    height:480px;

}

.box
{
    min-height:75px;
}
```

**Any help would be much appreciated!!**

Comment: Updated Code with the corrext syntax as pointed out by Rikudo! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use it like this:

```
$element.animate({marginLeft: "+=Npx"});
```

Where N is the number of pixels. [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/napRm/1/)

Comment: Mucho gracias, I knew it was much simpler than I was making it :-)

Comment: @user889962 No sweat. Make sure to accept an answer as correct when you get your answer, it will benefit the answerer, as well as the community and any future programmer which comes looking for the same question.

Comment: I just thought I'd mention it, since it's not necessarily obvious: It won't work if you put a whitespace between `=` and the number, so `+=5` will work, but `+= 5` won't.